# How to add a button on bottom to enter a new page?

Tags: flutter

I want to add a button on bottom on screen. And when I press on it, it enters a new section of text [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H6GV.jpg)

Comment: Hi! What exactly is the problem? Which code did you try? Please, be more specific.

Comment: Sir , i want to add text on bottom as i have added an image of sample.

Answer (score 0):

For a Button at the bottom of the Screen you can use a Floating Action Button in the Scaffold. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

For navigation you can use MaterialPage Route [Find the Link to Navigators here.](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Answer (score 0):

you can use raised button or any Text widget,here is an example

```
    InkWell( child: Text("Entry Price",
 style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,
 fontSize: 14.0.sp)),
 onTap: () { showCupertinoModalPopup
 ( context: context, builder:
 (context) => Infofavor());
```

=================================================